# Need a Query to sort out the Values from One table based on values of another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I am looking for a query to return a Column in Sale Table called as `MRP`. This table has some mistaken values of MRP. where as in `Purchase` table everything is in order and has right vales of MRP. Needed a query to return the values in the Sale Table which has No matching MRP in Purchase table for individual Item.

Sample Purchase Table

```
  Iid  CP        QUANTITY   MRP PRICE
  1   62.8  240  89 78
  1   57.5  240  89 79
  1  60.15  480  89 79
  2  60.14  720  89 79
  2  60.15  480  89 79
```

Sample Sales Table here 2nd row has the Mistaken MRP

```
  iid  CP   QTY MRP PRICE
  1   57.5  240 89  77
  1   57.5  40  81  79
  1   57.5  40  89  79
  1   62.8  40  89  72
  1   62.8  40  89  78
```

Needed a Query to show the id in Sales Table where the ItemID `iid` and MRP is mistakenly taken when not in the list of Purchases for the same Item

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `not exists()`

```
select *
from sale s
where not exists (
  select 1
  from purchase p
  where p.iid = s.iid
    and p.mrp = s.mrp
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZICIT13088

returns:

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+-------+
| iid | cp | qty | mrp | price |
+-----+----+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 | 58 |  40 |  81 |    79 |
+-----+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT IN clause to test for values that don't exist.  In your case, just source the "NOT IN" values from the purchase table:

```
SELECT MRP
FROM SalesTable
WHERE Iid NOT IN (SELECT IId FROM PurchaseTable)
```

This will return the MRP field for all rows in your sales table with "Iid" values that do not have a matching "Iid" value in the PurchaseTable.  Depending on your DB version, you may need to add `WHERE Iid IS NOT NULL` to your sub-select to work with the NOT IN.

You should also be able to use the `NOT EXISTS` operator to do the same thing.

Comment: It return Nothing, Sorry

Comment: Please post the exact query you ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, itemn, CAST(MRP AS NUMERIC(18,0)) as mrp, price
FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].DETAILSALE
WHERE  CAST(MRP AS NUMERIC(18,0)) NOT IN (SELECT CAST(MRP AS NUMERIC(18,0)) FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].DETAILPURCHASES) order by id, CAST(itemn AS NUMERIC(18,0)) asc
```

This Worked For me. Thanks for the Hint @ravioli